# opencv resize window for a live cam

Tags: opencv, resize, window, raspbian, face-detection

I've followed [this tutorial](https://blog.hackster.io/getting-started-with-the-intel-neural-compute-stick-2-and-the-raspberry-pi-6904ccfe963) and managed to make a face detection,age+gender like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghoWJUNuEj)

Now the problem I'm facing is that the window size of the application is very small and I don't know and can't find a way to resize it ([in this image](https://prnt.sc/p5zx0o) bottom right you can see the window).

The code of the applciation can be [found here](https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/tree/master/demos/interactive_face_detection_demo)

Answer (score 0):

Solution  whatever you set the size,,,opencv resize window for a live cam

```
import cv2

def main():
    windowName = "Main"
    cv2.namedWindow(windowName)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    print('Width :' + str(cap.get(3)))
    print('Height :' + str(cap.get(4)))

    cap.set(3, 620)
    cap.set(4, 720)




    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    else:
        ret = False

    while ret:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        output = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow(windowName, frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindow()

    cap.release()    

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```