# how to python opencv size increase and decrease window for a live cam

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

How can python opencv size increase and decrease window for a live cam.
The cammera work but I don,t how Its larger and smaller interface live cam.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opencv resize window for a live cam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57934288/opencv-resize-window-for-a-live-cam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution of your Questions.
Check it's Now..

Click  this  links...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61848405/13491597

After you whaterver set  your size whatever you want..